# Why is my list of figures all on one line?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, lists

Today I got the idea that I need a list of "things" in my document.  I don't have any figures so I planned to use the list of figures feature.  Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,pagesize=pdftex,openright,headings=twolinechapter,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of API Addresses}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\mainmatter

\addcontentsline{lof}{lof}{/api/SystemProperties}
\addcontentsline{lof}{lof}{/api/Foo}
\addcontentsline{lof}{lof}{/api/XXX}

\backmatter


\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

When I process the document, I get a list of figures that looks like this:

[image: document produced]

No line returns.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  All the examples I have seen from various sources have a nice numbered list with the page numbers tabbed to the right ... which is pretty much exactly what I would like.

I have another problem that in my real document *something* is putting addvspace, but because there is not end of the paragraph, LaTeX complains about the addvspace when not between paragraphs.  I think if I can fix the above, then this problem with addvspace will go away.

Comment: The second argument of the `\addcontentsline` macro should be `figure`.  Try `\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{/api/FOO}`.

Comment: You probably want to use \addcontents, unless you want the page number at the end of each line.

Comment: @GuM changing to figure worked.    Kormylo the addcontents give me "not defined".

Comment: Oops, \addtocontents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of the `\addcontentsline` macro should be `figure`.  For example, this code

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\renewcommand*{\listfigurename}{List of API Addresses}



\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{/api/SystemProperties}
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{/api/Foo}
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{/api/XXX}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.   And may I add .... the documentation and error messages are ABYSMAL.

Comment: @AgilePro: In what sense, “abysmal”?  What documentation are you reading?

Comment: See source2e.pdf from CTAN.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I assume you are referring to the comments that accompany the definition of the `\addcontentsline` macro; well, they are terse, but exact.

Answer (score 1):

`tocloft` is a package which allows to decide `list of ...` aspect, but also allows an easy declaration of new `table of whatever`. Following its documentation I've managed to do following example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, pagesize=pdftex, openright, headings=twolinechapter, chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listapiadd}{List of API addresses}
\newlistof{apiadd}{api}{\listapiadd}

\newcommand{\apiadd}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{apiadd}
    \texttt{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{api}{apiadd}{\protect\numberline{\theapiadd}\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter

This is an \apiadd{/api/SystemProperties}, and these are two more \apiadd{/api/Foo}, \apiadd{/api/XXX}.

\backmatter
\listofapiadd
\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]